# integer RGB and double alpha to DWORD and then cast to float

Tags: c++, directx

I need to convert a integer RGB color passed to my function shift double alpha which is between 0 and 1 into it and then push it back into an array of float.

```
#define __GETR(x) ((x & 0x0000FF))
#define __GETG(x) ((x & 0x00FF00)>>8)
#define __GETB(x) ((x & 0xFF0000)>>16)

// NOTE: The vertex format for this class should be written so that color is an integer and not float.
void AddColor(int col, double alpha)
{
  vertices.push_back(D3DCOLOR_RGBA(__GETR(col), __GETG(col), __GETB(col), (int)alpha*255));
  useColors = true;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have double underscores in your names, and never start names with underscore-capital. Those are reserved, and you might be causing hard-to-find, subtle errors. Just pick normal names.

Comment: Yes I can't really do anything about it, this is an open source project and someone else originally wrote that color definition in our OpenGL graphics system, I will be sure to remove those in the future though, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
int result = __GETR(x) * alpha;
```

The right-hand side is a floating point operation, so `__GETR(x)` is converted to a floating-point value before the multiplication; finally the result is truncated to fit into an `int`.

Comment: This what it looks like with my DX code http://www.gophoto.it/view.php?i=http://oi40.tinypic.com/or54kx.jpg

Comment: This what it should look like as it does in my OpenGL version http://oi39.tinypic.com/2w53cqv.jpg

Comment: The complete version of this code is available online for my open source project https://github.com/RobertBColton/enigma-dev/blob/master/ENIGMAsystem/SHELL/Graphics_Systems/Direct3D9/DX9model.cpp

Comment: With that information, can you please look again, because I believe I mislead you the first time with the code I posted.

Comment: @RobertBColton: Try just `alpha * 255`; drop the cast.

Comment: If I drop the cast I get the following error. `error: invalid operands of types 'double' and 'int' to binary 'operator&'`

Comment: @RobertBColton: This is like a silly version of "your princess is in another castle", and you won't post the actual code that's causing your problem... OK, one last try: `(int)(alpha * 255)`.

Comment: Oh, no you didn't see I updated the code. `vertices.push_back(D3DCOLOR_RGBA(__GETR(col), __GETG(col), __GETB(col), (int)alpha*255));` and that is a macro which creates a D3DCOLOR the reason is because color is generally stored as DWORD but I am hacking around this in DX to just have one big array of floats and trying to store this color as a float.